# Salesforce - Custom label as a button's content

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to find a way to make a button label dynamic and I couldn't find any other way than Custom Label. The only issue is I don't know how to make the MasterLabel to pick my custom label. I've tried these codes and no luck so far.

My custom label is 'Job'

```
  <masterLabel>{!System.Label.Job}</masterLabel>
```

I also tried these:

```
 <masterLabel>{!$Label.Job}</masterLabel>
 <masterLabel>$Label.Job</masterLabel>
 <masterLabel>System.Label.Job</masterLabel>
```

None worked :(

custom-object cu

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is your button to have the values of your custom label then all you need is to declare it like this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="{!$label.PKB2_Ask_Button}"></apex:commandButton>
```

this is  an example on a button I habe but it is the same. you just change it to your custom label.
I don't think you need the master label tag for that.

if that is not what you need then provide more details to understand what you need and why are you using masterlabel tags

Comment: it's not a visual force page. it's a salesforce default page

Comment: is this a detail page button?
where in the page are you using this button and how did you create it?